# Is Silvana's comment about the moon in her exchange with Mireille a real life quote?

Tags: noir

In episode 9 of *Noir*, Silvana meets Mireille and has a conversation with her, which the Funimation subtitles give as:

> S: I thought you would come here. Daughter of Corsica, Mireille. Mireille Bouquet …
>
> M: So you did see me.
>
> S: "The light of the moon is merciless, and exposes those who would hide."
>
> M: But how could you have remembered me? Once … Yes, we only met once before.
>
> S: You were trembling then too. And now, you are before me as a blade known by the name of Noir.

Silvana then gives Mireille "the kiss of death" and tells her where to find her the next day.

The line about "the light of the moon" sounds like a quotation that Silvana pulled out of somewhere, since the Funimation subtitles put quotation marks around it and since it has a "theatrical" quality to it. With this in mind, is Silvana quoting something that exists in real life? I tried searching for `"the light of the moon is merciless"` and only got results for *Noir*, but it's possible that I might have missed something.

Comment: Googling for the line in Japanese 「月の光は無慈悲。隠れたる者を暴き出す」 also just gives me _Noir_ results.